# Remove duplicates by rule from a big list

Tags: python

I have a list of 10.000 elements of custom objects. The important thing is that these objects have a graph as an attribute (consisting of something between 20 and 500 nodes).

Now I would like to remove all the duplicates in the list, where I assume two objects to be equal if and only if their graphs are isomorphic.

My code looks something like that:

```
import networkx as nx
#
def remove_duplicates(list_):
 
    filtered_list = list()
 
    while len(list_) > 0:
        A = list_.pop()
        filtered_list.append(A)
 
        for B in list_:
            if A.num_of_nodes == B.num_of_nodes:
                if nx.is_isomorphic(A.graph, B.graph, node_match=node_check):
                     list_.remove(B)

    return filtered_list
```

However, the program stops progressing at a certain point. I checked the activity monitor and apparently the memory is not an issue, but maybe the CPU.

Does someone have a hint on how to solve this a little bit more efficiently/elegantly? For smaller samples, my code worked well.

Comment: I'm guessing `nx.is_isomorphic` is probably worse than O(n).  Then you're calling it on *every* element in the input.  Plus `node_check`, which isn't shown here, has unknown complexity.  These are the big killers.  Can you 1. avoid computing isomorphic graphs at all?  2. fail faster?  This is currently the naive dedup algorithm: you need to look at speeding it up, or speeding up the steps in it.   (Separately there's *probably* a tiny performance hit from appending/popping vs. conditionally appending).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work as soon as you'll find something in `self.graph` that is identical for any other isomorphic graph, and put it in place of `???` (e.g. something like `self.graph.some_isomorphic_characteristic`)

```py
import networkx as nx
from typing import List

class custom_object:
    def __init__(self, num_of_nodes, graph):
        self.num_of_nodes = num_of_nodes
        self.graph = graph
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.num_of_nodes == other.num_of_nodes and nx.is_isomorphic(self.graph, other.graph, node_match=node_check)
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.num_of_nodes, ???))

def remove_duplicates(list_: List[custom_object]) -> List[custom_object]:
    return list(set(list_))
```

Otherwise you can use

```py
import networkx as nx
from typing import List

class custom_object:
    def __init__(self, num_of_nodes, graph):
        self.num_of_nodes = num_of_nodes
        self.graph = graph
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.num_of_nodes == other.num_of_nodes and nx.is_isomorphic(self.graph, other.graph, node_match=node_check)
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

def remove_duplicates(list_: List[custom_object]) -> List[custom_object]:
    filtered_list = []
    for obj in list_:
        add = True
        for filtered_obj in filtered_list:
            if obj == filtered_obj:
                add = False
                break
        if add:
            filtered_list.append(obj)
    return filtered_list
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. The first approach seem to work quite good, as there is indeed a way to hash a graph and almost preserve its isomorphism class. 

Now that I have defined __eq__, __neq__ and __hash__, how does the list(set(list_)) command identify duplicates? Only based on the hash? (That would make __eq__ and __neq__ redundant, wouldn't it?) Or does it somehow incorporate the hash AND the eq methods?

Comment: Sets in Python are unordered collections without repetition. Converting a list to a set automatically remove the repeated elements, identified by their hashes (equal hashes == repeated elements). Then list() converts the set back again to a list

Comment: So I would actually not need the __eq__ and __neq__ method, if I have a hash method defined?

Comment: Yes I think the hash method is just enough for the set function, but sadly I'm not 100% sure right now

Answer (score 1):

Does this help? I do think this method works from what I understand from your question:

```
import networkx as nx

def remove_duplicates(list_):
 
    for i in Counter(list_).items():
        if i[1] > 1:
            for v in range(i[1]-1):
                list_.remove(i[0])

    return list_
```

Basically we used the `Counter()` class from the `Collections` module. Basically we count how many times the same value is repeated in the list and then remove depending upon the number of times it repeated.

In your case the code might look like this:

I hope this answers your question.